# MVC model returns null

Tags: json, model-view-controller

I have a json string in my controller.  When i deserialize that into my model, it's returning a null value.  The very strange part here is that this was working a while ago then stopped.  Any thoughts as to what's wrong here?  This is an api call, so i don't have the luxury of changing the json either.  tCustLst is the problem child that is returning null from the model.

json (result):

`"{\"response\":{\"cErrorMessage\":\"\",\"moreRecordsAvailable\":false,\"tCustLst\":{\"t-custLst\":[{\"custNo\":324161.0,\"shipTo\":\"\",\"name\":\"TEST \\/ (NICKNAME)\",\"addr1\":\"P.O. BOX 111\",\"addr2\":\"\",\"city\":\"NYC\",\"state\":\"NY\",\"zipCd\":\"55555-1234\",\"ordBal\":0.0,\"totalBal\":20451.67,\"sortFld\":\"      123456\"}]}}}"`

controller code:

```
 CustomerList.Rootobject records = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomerList.Rootobject>(result);
 return View(records);
```

model:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebappsIntranet.Models
{
        public class CustomerList
        {

                public class Rootobject
                {
                        public string cErrorMessage { get; set; }
                        public bool moreRecordsAvailable { get; set; }            
                        public tCustLst tCustList { get; set; }
                }
                public class tCustLst
                {
                        [JsonProperty("t-custLst")]
                        public List<tCustcomerList> tcustomerlist { get; set; }
                }
                public class tCustcomerList {
                        public float custNo { get; set; }
                        public string shipTo { get; set; }
                        public string name { get; set; }
                        public string addr1 { get; set; }
                        public string addr2 { get; set; }
                        public string city { get; set; }
                        public string state { get; set; }
                        public string zipCd { get; set; }
                        public float ordBal { get; set; }
                        public float totalBal { get; set; }
                        public string sortFld { get; set; }
                }

        }
}
```

Comment: You expect `tCustList`, you have `tCustLst` instead.

Comment: Guess that's what happens when you look at this over and over and over....thanks @Gserg!  Totally missed that.  Kudos!